# about ## to connect macro and invoke different functions

Tags: c++, c, macros, preprocessor, definition

```
// file a.h

// #define MY_MACRO( size, name )
MY_MACRO( 1,    var_a )
MY_MACRO( 2,    var_b )
MY_MACRO( 3,    var_b )
MY_MACRO( 4,    var_b )
MY_MACRO( 5,    var_b )
MY_MACRO( 1024, var_c )
```

```
// file b.c

#define ARG_1( name ) fun_size_one( name )        // arg with size one
#define ARG_2( name ) fun_size_not_one( name )    // arg with size not one
#define ARG_3( name ) fun_size_not_one( name )    // arg with size not one
#define ARG_4( name ) fun_size_not_one( name )    // arg with size not one
#define ARG_5( name ) fun_size_not_one( name )    // arg with size not one
// #define ARG_...( name ) fun_size_not_one( name )    and so on

#define ARG( size, name ) ARG_##size( name )

/** here is use macro to invoke fun with different size */
#define MY_MACRO( size, name ) ARG( size, name )
#include "a.h"   // to invoke fun_size_one or fun_size_not_one
```

i have to define many ARG_1,2,3,4,5... to cover different size
is there any way to just use 2 macros like ARG_ONE and ARG_NOT_ONE, cover these size.

Comment: Preprocessor libraries have equality check macros, so you could use (or reinvent) one of those to test against 1.

Comment: hi @chris, could you give an example 
macro or function  of preprocessor libraries ,I will learn and search. thank you

Comment: I was referencing something like [`BOOST_PP_EQUAL`](https://cs.brown.edu/~jwicks/boost/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/equal.html) as the most direct functionality for what your code is doing right now. It would be used with `BOOST_PP_IF`.

Comment: hi @chris, I have searched boost pp library, and tested BOOST_PP_EQUAL, it is worked. But many PP macro have limit of arguments (maybe max 256), so I think eric's answer is the best way to solve this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//  Replace macro invocation with third argument.
#define Argument3(a, b, c,...)  c

/*  Select third argument, fun_size_not_one, unless x is replaced with a comma,
    which makes fun_size_one the third argument.  (There is a trailing comma
    so that the "..." in Argument3 receives at least one argument, albeit empty.)
*/
#define Auxiliary(x)    Argument3(x, fun_size_one, fun_size_not_one,)

//  Define ARG_1 to be replaced by a comma, to select fun_size_one above.
#define ARG_1 ,

//  Use the Auxiliary macro to select which function is desired.
#define MY_MACRO( size, name ) Auxiliary(ARG_##size) (name)

MY_MACRO( 1,    var_a )
MY_MACRO( 2,    var_b )
MY_MACRO( 3,    var_b )
MY_MACRO( 4,    var_b )
MY_MACRO( 5,    var_b )
MY_MACRO( 1024, var_c )
```

Results:

```
fun_size_one (var_a)
fun_size_not_one (var_b)
fun_size_not_one (var_b)
fun_size_not_one (var_b)
fun_size_not_one (var_b)
fun_size_not_one (var_c)
```

Comment: I have compiled my code with your method, you're right, thanks very much. Have a good day!

Comment: hi @Eric, `Argument3( x, fun_size_one, fun_size_not_one )`, with no comma at end is also worked, am i right? Use Gcc v4.9, the ". . ." receives empty, seems no warning or error

Comment: @molly: Some compilers accept it, but the C standard does not require that, so it is safer to use a comma. When programming, do not rely on what appears to work. Use specifications to know what should work.